# python numpy how to rotate 3d array along the center

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, rotation

I need to transform the following 3D array.
I need the 1'st column to become the 1'strow,
2'nd column to become 2'nd row, and 3'rd column to become 3'rd row.

```
 3  4  5       4  7  3
 7  1  2   =>  5  1  4
 4  5  6       6  2  5  

 6  7b 1       7b 3 6 
 3  4  5   =>  1  4 7b
 7b 1  2       2  5 1
```

this work  `print(np.rot90(r[6], 3))` but only
on 2d array, and I need it in a 3d array
I need it to work for this array

```
[[['6' '7b' '1']
  ['3' '4' '5']
  ['7b' '1' '2']]

 [['3' '4' '5']
  ['7' '1' '2']
  ['4' '5' '6']]

 [['7' '1' '2']
  ['4s' '5' '6']
  ['1' '2' '3']]]
```

Comment: can you share the expected output?

Comment: [`np.rot90`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.rot90.html) needs 2 **or more** dimensions. `np.rot90(arr, k=3, axes=(1,2))` is working fine with a 3D array. Please provide example data in a copyable format.

Answer (score 0):

It seems [`np.rot90`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/08772f91455db66810995db5e9d0671f91e027ed/numpy/lib/function_base.py#L158-L245) use [`np.transpose`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/08772f91455db66810995db5e9d0671f91e027ed/numpy/lib/function_base.py#L245) **internally**, so we can use `np.transpose` instead that directly for your case. IIUC, you can transpose the array for 2nd & 3rd dimensions and then reverse them as needed:

```
a.transpose([0, 2, 1])[:, :, ::-1]

# [[['7b' '3' '6']
#   ['1' '4' '7b']
#   ['2' '5' '1']]
# 
#  [['4' '7' '3']
#   ['5' '1' '4']
#   ['6' '2' '5']]
# 
#  [['1' '4s' '7']
#   ['2' '5' '1']
#   ['3' '6' '2']]]
```

It will get the same results as `np.rot90` that well explained by [@Szczesny in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14277722/michael-szczesny).